# Read and list elements of XSD in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd

We have an ERP that provides a webservices that has a CDATA field with the xsd definition of an specific data.

We can read this CDATA and it comes this way (not all fields are listed):

```
<EstPrdBR xmlns="http//tempuri.org/EstPrdBR.xsd"> 
<xsschema id="EstPrdBR" targetNamespace="http//tempuri.org/EstPrdBR.xsd" xmlnsmstns="http//tempuri.org/EstPrdBR.xsd" xmlns="http//tempuri.org/EstPrdBR.xsd" xmlnsxs="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlnsmsdata="urnschemas-microsoft-comxml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xselement name="EstPrdBR" msdataIsDataSet="true" msdataUseCurrentLocale="true" msdataEnforceConstraints="False"> 
        <xscomplexType> 
            <xschoice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
                <xselement name="TPRODUTO"> 
                    <xscomplexType> 
                        <xssequence> 
                            <xselement name="CODCOLPRD" msdataCaption="Coligada" type="xsshort" minOccurs="0" /> 
                            <xselement name="CODCOLIGADA" msdataCaption="Coligada" type="xsshort" /> 
                            <xselement name="IDPRD" msdataCaption="Identificador" type="xsint" default="1835" /> 
                            <xselement name="CODIGOPRD" msdataCaption="Código do Produto"> 
                                <xssimpleType> 
                                    <xsrestriction base="xsstring"> 
                                        <xsmaxLength value="30" /> 
                                    </xsrestriction> 
                                </xssimpleType> 
                            </xselement> 
                            <xselement name="NOMEFANTASIA" msdataCaption="Nome Fantasia"> 
                                <xssimpleType> 
                                    <xsrestriction base="xsstring"> 
                                        <xsmaxLength value="100" /> 
                                    </xsrestriction> 
                                </xssimpleType> 
                            </xselement> 
                            <xselement name="CODIGOREDUZIDO" msdataCaption="Código Reduzido" minOccurs="0"> 
                                <xssimpleType> 
                                    <xsrestriction base="xsstring"> 
                                        <xsmaxLength value="10" /> 
                                    </xsrestriction> 
                                </xssimpleType> 
                            </xselement> 
                            <xselement name="CODFAB" msdataCaption="Código do Fabricantes" minOccurs="0"> 
                                <xssimpleType> 
                                    <xsrestriction base="xsstring"> 
                                        <xsmaxLength value="15" /> 
                                    </xsrestriction> 
                                </xssimpleType> 
                            </xselement> 
                            (...)
    </xselement> 
</xsschema>
```

So I need to read the element name, caption and attributes fields witch are:

- Fields: CODCOLIGADA, IDPRD, CODIGOPRD, NOMEFANTASIA,etc
- Specifications: Caption, minOccurs, type (string) and maxLen

I´ve been trying, without success, to use XMLDOM and simple_xml to do the job, any ideas?

I´ve tried to use Goebas (https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd-reader, but without success too.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you've made attempts, show them, describe the results, and describe how that differs from what you want.

Comment: You can parse it as xml string (perhaps removing the namespaces) with xpath `xmllint --xpath '//xselement[@name="CODCOLIGADA"]/@msdataCaption' test.xml` returns `msdataCaption="Coligada"`.